# Revenant folders on my Nexus 7 (flo) - how to track down the culprit?

Tags: nexus-7, moon-reader

This may have been going on for a while, but I have only noticed a few weeks ago.

There are some folders **inside** the `Downloads` folder (i.e. subfolders and subsubfolders) which originally contained documents meant for a particular period and thus were named after year and month (e.g. `2014-05`).

They contained documents which I have read in apps like *Moon+ Reader*.

I deleted those (sub)subfolders many times now, but they keep coming back.

My first hunch was: "oh, somehow *Moon+ Reader* must have registered them in its DB and keeps recreating them". So I decided to use the rudimentary file browser included in that app and removed the folders there. Yet, after every reboot they keep reappearing.

How can I track down the culprit? Is *Moon+ Reader* perhaps known to behave like that?

Comment: Default folders like `Downloads, Music, Movies etc.` are recreated every time Android checks for them (periodically or after every reboot) and thus are not meant to be deleted. Even you put an empty SD card in your phone, it would always get filled with empty, default folders, for easy file/document sorting.

Comment: @GiantTree: yeah, but my question isn't at all about those "system folders". It's about subfolders (actually subsubfolders) of them. And those should be mine to manage.

Comment: Well, that's weird. That shouldn't happen except a special app creates them.

Comment: @GiantTree: yep, that's my problem. How to track down that culprit :)

Answer (score 1):

I have now been able to confirm without doubt that indeed *Moon+ Reader* is responsible for the folders reappearing after deletion.

The problem is that I've come up empty-handed when looking for a database or text file related to *Moon+ Reader* which contains the names of those folders.

Meanwhile I have moved my books into the `Books` folder instead of leaving it in a subfolder of `Download`, but now the whole folder hierarchy inside `Download` which was used by *Moon+ Reader* keeps reappearing.

Unfortunately even rating the app requires a Google+ account which I will not create and there is no support contact given. So no way to report this issue back. But I am thinking about extracting the app and trying to find the offending code to add more details here.

Comment: "*The problem is that I've come up empty-handed when looking for a database or text file related to Moon+ Reader which contains the names of those folders.*" -- for confirmation only, have you looked into the data directory of this app (under `/data/data`)?

Comment: @Firelord: yes, correct. That's the place I looked at.